# java convert string to file for JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing

```
        String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
        "Text files", "txt");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(currentDir);
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       String fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
       System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
            fileName);
```

I'm trying to modify the JFileChooser, ShowOpenDialog example to use the current directory of the java package, using System.getProperty("user.dir") which returns a string, but setCurrentDirectory(File) wants File object. How do I convert the String to a File? Thanks.

Comment: `new File(fileName)` should work according to the Java API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String). Also, please consider changing the title of your question to: `How do I convert the String to a File?`.

Answer (score 1):

Its relatively easy...

```
File file = new File("example_file.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
....
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(currentDir));
```

Answer (score -1):

> How do I convert the String to a File?

How about this?

```
    String str = "C:\1.txt";
    File file = Paths.get(str).toFile();
```

Comment: It compiles perfectly fine. Are you using Java 7 (or earlier)?

Comment: Right, it does, sorry about that. It probably also does not do what it think it does. Did you try printing `str`?